# Sliding out when a div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a website and I want it to be just one index page. And when you land, there will be a couple rows [like this](https://gyazo.com/83d4c857c68d3bfdae77b0aab3c9abc1) and when you click a row, it will expand the information that's been hiding to the bottom so it looks [like this](https://gyazo.com/bcd2bd9a119589ae670ea0d2d8213886).

Now I searched around and I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/webcarvers/8ZFMJ/34/) and I essentially copied and pasted the thing onto a new file just to fool around with it but it didn't work. I added the html tags, and important the proper files and such, well my code looks  like this.

```
//Index
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="slide.js"></script>   

<div class="container">
    <div class="one">Click me to reveal new div</div>
    <div class="two">Hey it worked!
        <br>New Contenttt</div>
</div>
</html>

//main.css
 .container {
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 60px;
}
.one {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #FFC300;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.two {
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s;
    -moz-transition: top 1s;
    -o-transition: top 1s;
    transition: top 1s;
}
/*.one:hover + .two {
    top: 0px;
}*/

//slide.jsvar clicked=true;
$(".one").on('click', function(){
    if(clicked)
    {
        clicked=false;
        $(".two").css({"top": 0});
    }
    else
    {
        clicked=true;
        $(".two").css({"top": "-40px"});
    }
});
```

However it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: add your jquery code in <script> .....code... </script>

Comment: uh you may want to add a <head> and <body> element to your html and you seem to have commented out var clicked=true in slide.js

Comment: Oh wait... did you just dump that whole thing into index.html or something?

Comment: also your link to slide.js is wrong. It should be  <script src="slide.js"></script>

Comment: check for any console errors in browser!! Otherwise it just **[works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/e43fhp7n/)** but with one minor change..

Comment: @sagarkodte No need to add `script` here because OP has kept it in a separate js file..

Comment: ohhh then okay and what about source for slide.js?

Comment: The js code mentioned is considered to be having in `slide.js`

Comment: Yeah I have it on a different file,  I have my slide.js saved in the same folder. And @Guruprasad Rao, I changed the true to false like in your code, yet it still doesn't work, unless im missing something else aswell

Comment: I havent changed true to false but I have exchanged code which slides from true to false..

Answer (score 0):

```
var clicked=true;
```

is commented out. Uncomment this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: On my actual file I do have it uncommented, I just messed up when copy and pasting

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function (event) {
                $(".one").on('click', function(){
                    $(".two").slideToggle('fast')
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style>
             .container {
                overflow:hidden;
                height: 60px;
            }
            .one {
                background-color: #FFC300;          
                cursor:pointer;
            }
            .two {
                display:none; /* delete this line if you want to show your yellow div by default*/
                background-color: yellow;           
            }
    </style>
    </head>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="one">Click me to reveal new div</div>
        <div class="two">Hey it worked!
        <br>New Contenttt</div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how is your markup since in your previous answer you comment you have written

> I just messed up when copy and pasting

Here is the complete mark up including JS and CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>

 .container {
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 60px;
}
.one {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #FFC300;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.two {
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s;
    -moz-transition: top 1s;
    -o-transition: top 1s;
    transition: top 1s;
}

 </style>

 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="one">Click me to reveal new div</div>
    <div class="two">Hey it worked!
        <br>New Contenttt</div>
</div>
 <script>

       var clicked=true;
       $(".one").on('click', function(){
    if(clicked)
      {
        clicked=false;
        $(".two").css({"top": 0});
    }
    else
    {
        clicked=true;
        $(".two").css({"top": "-40px"});
    }
});
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

NOTE: I include the `body` , & `head` tag. Also please update are you referring the css and js from external file.Currently I have referring CSS and JS from same page

[WORKING DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ijV1RIr3mjTzJXYFpDuq?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> to <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> in index.html
```

and `<script type="slide.js"></script>` to `<script src="slide.js"></script>`
and embed your code in `$(document).ready( function () { });`
and Uncomment `var clicked=true;`

Final code will be

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="slide.js"></script>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="one">Click me to reveal new div</div>
        <div class="two">Hey it worked!
            <br>New Contenttt</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

slide.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var clicked = true;
$(".one").on('click', function() {
    if (clicked)
    {
        clicked = false;
        $(".two").css({"top": 0});
    }
    else
    {
        clicked = true;
        $(".two").css({"top": "-40px"});
    }
});
```

});

main.css

```
.container {
overflow:hidden;
height: 60px;
}
.one {
position: relative;
top: 0;
background-color: #FFC300;
z-index: 1;
cursor:pointer;
}
.two {
position: relative;
top: -40px;
background-color: yellow;
z-index: -1;
-webkit-transition: top 1s;
-moz-transition: top 1s;
-o-transition: top 1s;
transition: top 1s;
}
/*.one:hover + .two {
top: 0px;
}*/
```